# Buble Sort ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Preciso ordenar um array baseado no campo Data do mesmo, para isso fiz esse código.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");           
for(int i = 0; i < arrayCapacitacaoAux.size(); i++){
    String dadosA = (String)arrayCapacitacaoAux.get(i);
    String infoA[] = dadosA.split("\\|");                   
    Date dataA = (Date)format.parse(infoA[9]);

    for(int j = 0; j < arrayCapacitacaoAux.size()-i; j++){
        String dadosB = (String)arrayCapacitacaoAux.get(j);
        String infoB[] = dadosB.split("\\|");   
        Date dataB = (Date)format.parse(infoB[9]);

        if (dataA.after(dataB)) {

        }

    }

}
```

Tem algumas coisas que preciso dizer antes.

1. Não criei o código a principio, é um ajuste então não pude interferir no código, segue amostra de como o array é preenchido. Segue amostra de como é feito:

`arrayCapacitacaoAux.add(pageContext.getAttribute("data").toString()+"|"+nomeCurso +"|"+local+"|"+imagemApresentacao+"|"+horario +"|"+cargaHoraria +"|"+publicoAlvo+"|"+paginaEdit+"|"+periodo+"|"+dataFinal);`

E por isso eu pego os dados da forma que esta no codigo em que postei.

2. A ideia é que a data superior (AFTER) estivesse sempre acima.

Enfim, cheguei nessa parte e meio que me perdi, a unica vez que fiz o Buble sort foi em C, mas não muda tanto, o problema é que agora estou usando arraylist, podem me dar um help nessa ? Obrigado galera!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar um `Comparator` com as regras de ordenação que você deseja e depois utilizar o método `Collections.sort`. Exemplo:

```
List<String> arrayCapacitacaoAux = new ArrayList<>();
arrayCapacitacaoAux.add("data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|01/01/2016");
arrayCapacitacaoAux.add("data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|02/01/2016");
arrayCapacitacaoAux.add("data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|05/04/2016");
arrayCapacitacaoAux.add("data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|01/01/2017");

Collections.sort(arrayCapacitacaoAux, new Comparator<String>() {

    private final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public final int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(o1.split("\\|")[9], dtf);
        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(o2.split("\\|")[9], dtf);
        return date2.compareTo(date1);
    }
});

arrayCapacitacaoAux.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Saída:

```
data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|01/01/2017
data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|05/04/2016
data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|02/01/2016
data|nomeDoCurso|local|imagemApresentacao|horario|cargaHoraria|publicoAlvo|paginaEdit|periodo|01/01/2016
```